# Dragging formula, pattern changes

Tags: google-sheets

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How do I keep the same order when dragging the formula, I want A6 to be 3 and not 5.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following formula instead of `=B1`

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$10,ROW()/2)
```

If you want to populate the entire column withjust a formula, then this should do the trick:

```
=IF(ROW()/2 = ROUND(ROW()/2,0),INDEX(B$1:B$10,ROW()/2),"name")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you please help me one more time, I have been breaking my head for the past 2 hours but with no success. This example is a bit harder, but the idea is pretty much the same. 

b2=k1, b4=l1, b6=m1, b8=n1, b10=o1

What should be the formula for b2,4,6,8,10 so when I drag it second block would take the numbers from K1,L1,M1,N1,O1 instead of K12,L12,M12,N12,O12

I really tried to understand it, but I cannot.

Here is the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/26oti0i

Comment: Change the Range you index: `INDEX(N$1:U$1,ROW()/2)`

Comment: I have tried, that didnt work. Can you check the screenshot or this topic? I have attached the screenshots there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991850/google-sheets-copy-drag-formula?noredirect=1#comment125498518_70991850

Comment: Received an answer in another topic the link is above if someone ever faces a similar situation.