# Google sheets copy drag formula

Tags: google-sheets, count, limit, offset, google-query-language

[image]
[image]

How do I copy purple numbers from the right side when using a copy-drag? What should be the formula for it to work?

Comment: add more details what you are trying to acomplish

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: In the first screenshot B2=K1, B4=L1 B6=M1 B8=N1 B10=O1.
When I drag the bordered block  I want to get the purple in cells B15=K2, B17=L2 B19=M3 B21=N4 B22=O5. However, when I drag the formula I get data from line 14 and not line 2.

Comment: Hopefully, it's clear enough. The idea is to have a separate block that will copy the data from the first line from the right side, then when I copy the block a second block will copy the data from the second line from the right side, and so on. But I cannot do it manually as the lists on the right side are huge and this is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B2 will be:

```
=K1
```

and for every next cell use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(INDIRECT("K1:O")), "Limit 1 offset "&
 SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()-1), FLATTEN(INDIRECT("K1:O")))), ))
```

can be dragged but since you need it in every 2nd row you can just copy-paste it wherever you need so

Comment: Wow! It actually worked. Is there a way to take the data from another page?

Comment: @Edvard change both `K1:O` to `sheetname!K1:O`

Comment: Much appreciated, there is no way I could have written this in million years.